# Java Jsoup parsing span but the class name is " "

Tags: java

I use jsoup to parsing information from https://www.bitfinex.com/t/BTC:USD but class from html is " " and I can't find the way to deal with this blank class pls help me >-<

```
<span class=" " style="padding: 0px 2px;">7,618.0</span>
```

my lastest code

```
public static String getPrice() throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.bitfinex.com/t/BTC:USD");//url import
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 7000);
            Elements elements = doc.select("span");//choose class body
            elements = elements.getClass(" ");
            String s = elements.text();
            System.out.println("XrpBf :"+s);
            return s;
        }
```

and  I got this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getClass() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (String)

```
at arbitrage.BtcBf.getPrice(BtcBf.java:21)
at arbitrage.BtcBf.main(BtcBf.java:14)
```

Comment: It's getElementsByClass​(String className) and not getClass()

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a class name which is " ". Let's forget that you somehow started to believe that it is. Instead tell us what is the situation, by explaining what it is that you're seeing with your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The basic mistake here is that you are using Java's own [getClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--), which has nothing to do with JSoup and returns a [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object.

Use the following:

```
Elements withClassName = doc.select(".className");
```

Note an empty CSS class does absolutely nothing. You may be better off checking the attribute value is equal to a string with one space in it if this HTML is not your own and you cannot correct it.